# How to get the Id of element executing in loop on the button clicked placed outside the loop?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am having input type with different id's executing in *ngFor . I want to get the id's and data of all the input types in which the user has entered the text on the button click placed outside the *ngFor . Here is the code I have written :

```
Angular HTML Code --

<div *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] ; let i = index" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <input type="text" (value)="Value=$event" id="val-{{i}}"></input>
</div>

<div>  
    <button type="button" (click)="add();">Add</button>
</div>
```

```
Angular Typescript Code --

Value:string;
val:string;
 add(){
    console.log("Value:"+this.Value+"  -- "+this.val);

  }
```

I am getting the result for this.value only but I am not getting this.val.

So if anyone can guide how to get both the values and ids of the entered text input box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ViewChildren to get all the input elements as an querylist. You have to set the reference in HTML.

HTML COde:

```
<input type="text" #inputTag (value)="Value=$event" id="val{{i}}" />
```

Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChildren('inputTag') inputTag: QueryList<any>;

  add() {
    console.log(this.inputTag);
    this.inputTag.map((tag) => {
      // Below line will get all the ids of the input tag.
      console.log(tag.nativeElement.id);
    })
  }
}
```

After this, you can add filter operation to filter out the empty inputs

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined . It is giving me the error.Also

Comment: Stackblitz-link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ywxro?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I think you haven't add the reference in the HTML. Just take a look at the above stackblittz code

Comment: But this will give me all the id's and my requirement is I only need the id's of those textbox in which I am adding the data.

Comment: Add the filter to remove the empty objects. I have modified the stackblitz link.

Comment: but still I need to loop through all the elements . I am looking directly and exactly for that element which have values . Is it possible without the loop, filtering and all.

Comment: Since I have used viewchildren, I think it is not possible to get the ids without iteration. You can try using reactive forms and iterate over the formarray in HTML.